# How to get process relative time

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Is there any way to get the process's execution time without using `GetTickCount` and `System Time` inside a C++ application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [`GetProcessTimes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223.aspx) function.

Comment: I think I've heard or red a long time ago that there is way to make error in our application and then get last error's time with an API. Is it possible?

Comment: I have never heard of anything like that in the API.